# Multiple subfigures in a row in a LaTeX document

Tags: latex

I am trying to insert four figures in a LaTeX document but if I use subfigure command, two of my figures stay in first row and the other two go to the second line. Like this :
 [image]

The other solution I tried was using minipage command, but the problem with minipage is that the subfigures get normal figure caption (like Figure 1) while I would like subfigure captions like (a). See the following figure:
[image]

What I prefer is to have something like second picture but with the captions like first picture.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your figures are too wide to fit side-by-side in one line. If multiple `subfigures` do not fit in one line, latex does an auto linebreak. You have to specify the width of each included graphic per `subfigure` such, that it will sum up to be smaller than the `\textwidth` parameter, i.e:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}
    \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
    \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

leads to

[image]

While if you set the width too high, e.g. `width=0.5\textwidth` leads to what I believe is your problem

[image]

Comment: What is that image? :-o

Comment: @xxx--- Mona Lisa with a facehugger from the Alien franchise

Comment: And don't forget to add \usepackage{subfigure} in the main latex file.

Comment: Awesome example. Thank you!

Comment: this gives the error Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...dth]{\includegraphics[]{name.png}}

Comment: @develarist please check in your preamble, that you use `\usepackage{subfigure}` and not `\usepackage{subcaption}` for the code here. If using subcaption, the code gives the error you described. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525978/subfigure-missing-number-treated-as-zero-and-illegal-unit-of-measure-pt-inser), for more details

Comment: I think that the reliance of this solution on subfigure is a severe drawback. Subfigure is deprecated, mainly due to a conflict with with hyperref.

Comment: Following @ckrk 's comment, another possibility might be based on `subcaption` as described at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables

Answer (score 7):

Although it's been a long time since the question was asked but the solution @gehbiszumeis offered didn't work for me and I still got the normal figure caption for each subfigure. So in case anyone has still the same problem as mine here is what I did (according to [this](https://shantoroy.com/latex/add-subfig-in-latex/)):

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{FIRST IMAGE}  
    \caption{}
    \label{SUBFIGURE LABEL 1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{SECOND IMAGE}  
    \caption{}
    \label{SUBFIGURE LABEL 2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{THIRD IMAGE}  
    \caption{}
    \label{SUBFIGURE LABEL 3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{FOURTH IMAGE}  
    \caption{}
    \label{SUBFIGURE LABEL 4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FIGURE CAPTION}
\label{FIGURE LABEL}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

If some cannot get the subfigure's caption, like (a) (b) (c) and (d), me neither.

One solution is to replace the "[]" in "\subfigure[]" with "(a)",
just like:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  
  \subfigure(a){\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
  \subfigure(b){\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}} 
  \subfigure(c){\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}
  \subfigure(d){\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{monalisa.jpg}}

  \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
 
\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please use codeblocks